# Editing user info using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I've built a cms interface for the admin in my website. among other things the admin can add\edit users info using forms.
when I send the edit form I keep getting this error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'` which suggests that the DB update is trying to save all of the request indexes (which contains values of columns from other table) and not just the one I'm trying to update.

I've manage to track the problem to one line `$user_role->save();`.
the lines above that do what their suppose to (finding thr correcct user_role and change its value).

**Here is my code**

**Model**

```js
static public function update_user($request, $id){
        
        $image_name = '';

        if( !empty($request['profile_image']) && $request->hasFile('profile_image') && $request->file('profile_image')->isValid() ){

            $file = $request->file('profile_image');
            $image_name = date('Y.m.d.H.i.s') . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file('profile_image')->move( public_path() . '/images/profile-images/' , $image_name);
            $img = Image::make( public_path() . '/images/profile-images/' . $image_name );
            $img->resize(370, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $img->save();

        }
        $user = self::find($id);
        $user->name = $request['name'];
        $user->email = $request['email'];
        $user->phone = $request['phone'];
        if( !empty($request['password']) ){
            $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        }
        if(!empty($image_name)){
            $user->profile_image = $image_name;
        }
        if( !empty($request['role_id']) ){
            $user_role = Users_role::find($id);
            $user_role->role_id = $request['role_id'];
            $user_role->save();
        }
        $user->save();
        Session::flash('sm', 'Your profile has been updated');
        Session::flash('sm-position', 'toast-top-center');
        Session::put('user_name', $request['name']);
    }
```

**View**

```js
<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="module message">
                <div class="module-head">
                    <h3><b>Edit Product</b></h3>
                </div><br>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="module message">
                            <div class="module-body">
                                    <form action="{{ url('cms/users/' . $user->id) }}" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <div class="module-body">
                                            @method('PUT')
                                            @csrf
                                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id}}">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <div class="w-100 field-input-cms">
                                                <label for="category-id" class="input-group-text h-50"><span class="text-danger">*</span><b> Permissions:</b></label>
                                                <select name="role_id" class="custom-select span-8">
                                                    <option @if ( $user->role_id == 8 ) selected="selected" @endif value="8">Admin</option>
                                                    <option @if ( $user->role_id == 2 ) selected="selected" @endif value="2">Regular</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <small class="text-muted help-text">Please select one option</small><br>
                                            <span class="text-danger">&nbsp; {{ $errors->first('category_id') }}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="w-100 field-input-cms">
                                            <label for="name" class="input-group-text h-100"><span class="text-danger">*</span><b> Name:</b></label>        
                                            <input type="text" value="{{ $user->name }}" name="name" style="width:100%" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
                                        </div>
                                        <small class="text-muted help-text">Name of user</small><br>
                                        <span class="text-danger">&nbsp; {{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                                        <div class="field-input-cms w-100">
                                            <label for="email" class="input-group-text"><span class="text-danger">*</span><b> Email:</b></label>        
                                            <input type="text" value="{{ $user->email }}" name="email" size="120" class="form-control mw-100" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
                                        </div>
                                        <small class="text-muted text-balck help-text"> Email of user</small><br>
                                        <span class="text-danger">&nbsp; {{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                                        <div class="field-input-cms w-100">
                                            <label for="phone" class="input-group-text"><span class="text-danger">*</span><b> Phone:</b></label>        
                                            <input type="text" value="{{ $user->phone }}" name="phone" size="120" class="form-control mw-100" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
                                        </div>
                                        <small class="text-muted text-balck help-text"> Phone number of user</small><br>
                                        <span class="text-danger">&nbsp; {{ $errors->first('phone') }}</span>
                                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Upload</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="custom-file">
                                                    <input type="file" name="profile_image" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                                                    <label class="custom-file-label" name="profile_image" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <small class="text-muted help-text">Image must be: jpg, jpeg, png, gif. Max: 5mb</small><br>
                                            <span class="text-danger">&nbsp; {{ $errors->first('profile_image') }}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <img id="cms-profile-image" src="{{ asset('images/' . $user->profile_image) }}" >
                                        </div><br>
                                        <a class="btn btn-inverse" href="{{ url('cms/users') }}">Cancel</a>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Save Product" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>        
        </div> <!--/.content-->
    </div><!--/.span9-->
</div>
```

**Image of the error gaven by laravel**

[image]

I should mention that if I comment out this code:

```js
        if( !empty($request['role_id']) ){
            $user_role = Users_role::find($id);
            $user_role->role_id = $request['role_id'];
            $user_role->update();
        }
```

all the values are saved correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If your `users` table doesn't have `created_at` and `updated_at` columns you should set:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

in your `User` model.

Laravel by default assumes you have those fields for tables. So whenever record is created/updated it will automatically set/update those fields.

Alternatively you can update your table structure to add those fields and then those fields will be automatically handled by Laravel (in such case don't set `timestamps` to false).

You might be interested to read about [Eloquent conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)